# PHP: calling domain.com/filename/id1234

Tags: php

how do i setup my php file so it can be called from domain.com/filename.php?id=12345 to domain.com/filename/12345 ?

THANKS!

Comment: Google "**Apache URL Rewriting**". These things require access to webserver configuration files, since PHP doesn't handle those requests directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Create a file in your document root called `.htaccess` and place the following lines.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^filename/([0-9]+)/?$ filename.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Short and sweet :)

Comment: What if in future i decided to add in another paramenter ? domain.com/filename.php?id=12345&image_id=abc1234 ?

Comment: @jimmit In this case you'll need to adjust your rewrite rule according to your needs. Extend both the left and the right part as you need. Check the documentation, there are more examples.